Restore corrupted LUKS header after falsely creating GPT table over FDE LUKS device
I accidentally created a partition table of type GPT and a partition starting at 15GB and ending at 20GB with parted on a device with with 4001GB size and LUKS full disk encryption. The device either has been using LUKS full disk encryption or one LUKS partition filling the whole device, but presumably the former.
There is no backup which I could restore from, both in terms of data and also in terms of LUKS header.
What I tried so far:

sudo hexdump -C -n 30MB /dev/sdd | grep LUKS: No output
sudo hexdump -C -n 30MB /dev/sdd | grep key: Output:
000442e0  6b 65 79 c1 2c 58 16 4d  c2 74 d2 4e fc 0a f4 3e  |key.,X.M.t.N...>|
Restoring the LUKS header as described here, by running the following commands in order:

sudo head -c 16M /dev/sdd > luksheaderdamage.img
printf 'LUKS\272\276\0\2' |  dd bs=1 count=8 conv=notrunc of=luksheaderdamage.img
printf 'SKUL\272\276\0\2' |  dd bs=1 count=8 seek="$((0x4000))" conv=notrunc of=luksheaderdamage.img
sudo cryptsetup repair luksheaderdamage.img. Output: Device “luksheaderdamage.img” is not a valid LUKS device.



Is there any way to restore the LUKS header and device data?
Edit:
Since the LUKS device was created at the end of 2023 on Debian 11 with cryptsetup luksFormat standard parameters, I would assume it is LUKS version 2, but not sure.
Tried the second part of the mentioned guide:
sudo head -c 512MB /dev/sdd > luksheaderdamage2.img
stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d luksheaderdamage2.img | grep '"keyslots":'
stdbuf -oL strings -n 64 -t d luksheaderdamage2.img | grep 'LUKS'

Result: No output
Edit2:
Ran a search for common terms in LUKS headers:
sudo stdbuf -oL strings -t d /dev/sdb | grep --line-buffered 'LUKS\|aes-xts\|keyslots\|luks\|hash\|salt\|argon2\|sha256\|tokens\|stripes\|encryption\|key_size\|json\|segments\|digest\|crypt\|iterations' > luks-search-2024-05-14.txt & :
373447645 json
1259117503 hash*
1468572822 hash`\
2948552276 hashb|
7169609134 hash
8051395414 luks
8409050173 LUKS
8690006252 'Bsalt
9966507331 }LUKS]
10578915321 wJ lmLUKS
12292096512 LUKS
13653759009 LUKS
13673974863 salt
13697151377 LUKS
16348873768 luks
18736671145 LUKS2/
20186942339 LUKS
20349033366 qdsalt
21123169101 salt%{
25378731436 salt
25799187083 hash
27814694577 json2SW
28824314201 pklyNsalt
28935813813 LUKS
30657005211 hash0qb
30901139118 json|
32195940259 8salt
32262660305 LUKS
33741874123 8LUKSN
34848083555 salt&"
34913821500 LUKS~
36217398840 fgZluks
36791517331 saltTz
37485260912 luks
38184051776 O=nluks
39305094713 LUKS
39317013887 '[hashp1
39892599727 hashF

Can anyone confirm the correctness of the search command and, with that new result, that there is nothing which can be done to recover my data?

luks1 or luks2? if luks2, did you try the "part two" from the guide you linked?

hexdump | grep can fail (hexdump wraps text every 16 bytes after all and it would not match 'ke'(next line)'y' for 'key'), however if there were any LUKS 2 header at the start of disk, that should have found something anyhow. If it was LUKS 1 instead, it's probably gone, sorry…

@frostschutz : Since the LUKS device was created at the end of 2023 on a Debian 11 with cryptsetup luksFormat standard parameters, I would assume it is LUKS version 2, but not sure. Tried the second part of the guide without success. See edit.

If it really was at the start of the disk it seems that something wiped it completely. If you're not sure, let it scan a larger area or the whole device. No other ideas here, sorry.

@frostschutz : How can I work around that hexdump | grep can fail? Is there a better command to scan the disc for keywords?

Using strings like already shown is the "work around" (for grep LUKS you'd have to use strings -n 4 instead of -n 64, this is the minimum string length). But I doubt this is the problem in your case. I mentioned it just in case. Another string you could look for is aes-xts-plain64 (assuming you used default settings for encryption). You can also look at hexdump directly without grep, at offsets 0 (whole disk) or 1 MiB (most common offset for partition 1).

@frostschutz: Thank you. I updated my post with a new search for multiple keywords on the whole device. Can you confirm that the search command is correct and that there is nothing which can be done to restore my data with that new result?

Basically what your result shows is that there presumably is gigabytes of random data. With random data, it's not unexpected for short strings to pop up. You could grep /dev/urandom with similar results. So, quite possibly, that's your data right there. Just without a valid header (header backup, or knowing the master key), there's 0 chance to decrypt it at all.

Is the master key not the one with which I set up the encryption with cryptsetup? How can I derive this key?

LUKS generates a completely random master key. Your passphrase merely unlocks it. That's also how you can change your passphrase anytime. The master key is unrelated and stays the same. Otherwise you'd have to re-encrypt all data. Unfortunately with LUKS the header (key material, metadata) is a single point of failure, once it's gone, it's game over.

What I don't understand is how a partition table and a partition starting much later, can completely override a LUKS header, without any trace left. Shouldn't the LUKS header be much larger? Or did I make a mistake somewhere in the process of searching for the LUKS header?
